# PCA and FastICA in scikit-learn giving near identical results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

So after importing my data, transforming it, and splitting into training and test sets I tried running this script for PCA:

```
pca = PCA(random_state=2, n_components=2).fit_transform(X_train)
pca = pd.DataFrame(pca, columns=["X1","X2"]).assign(y = np.array(y_train))
pca.plot.scatter(x='X1', y='X2', c='y', colormap='viridis')
```

Giving me this graph

[image: PCA Top 2]

I then ran this script for ICA:

```
ica = FastICA(random_state=34, n_components=2).fit_transform(X_train)
ica = pd.DataFrame(ica, columns=["X1","X2"]).assign(y = np.array(y_train))
ica.plot.scatter(x='X2', y='X1', c='y', colormap='viridis')
```

[image: ICA 2 Components]

If you look closely, you'll see these graphs are exactly the same. Except flipped over the X1 axis. Any idea what could cause this? I was expecting ICA to produce something very different from PCA

Comment: How many features does your original data `X_train` have?

Comment: 15 before one-hot encoding, and 110 afterwards

Comment: Why do you expect them to be different? Have you seen this tutorial: https://blog.paperspace.com/dimension-reduction-with-independent-components-analysis/. There is a rotation in PCA that it is not necessarily in ICA. And if variables are gaussian, ICA is not required and PCA is sufficient meaning that they end up giving you the same results! You gotta read more about their fundamental differences.

Comment: Also see this one: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~nsjones/TalkSlides/HyvarinenSlides.pdf